# Choosing two numbers $a,b,$ such that the Euclidean algorithm takes 10 steps

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

The question is to find $2$ integers $a$,$b$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$ for which when applying the Euclidean Algorithm for finding the $\gcd \left(a,b\right)$ precisely $10$ steps are required.
This is what I have done:
Let $\left(a,b\right)$ = $\left(427,264\right)$
The $10$ steps for the $\gcd \left(427,264 \right)$ are as follows:

$427=264 \cdot 1+163$

$264=163\cdot1+101          $

$163=101\cdot1+62   $

$101=62\cdot1+39     $

$62=39\cdot1+23        $

$39=23\cdot1+16             $

$23=16\cdot1+7               $

$16=7\cdot2+2               $

$7=2\cdot3+1             $

$2=1\cdot2+0$

I just wanna know if what I have done is right??? or if possible note the place I gone wrong??

Comment: How did you find $a$ and $b$? I imagine the person who asked this question would want to see some explanation, I know I would.

Comment: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/gcf-euclids-algorithm.php

Comment: Maybe I am too literal, but as the question is worded it seems producing the numbers should be enough.  In a sense the issue is if you did a computer search until you found one, is that acceptable?  Seems to me it is.  Also if you just imagined one pair and tried it and it worked.  This is more English or math course taking strategy than mathematics.

Comment: Actually I worked backward to get the pairs.... so I am thinking that there will be more pairs that would be the solution to this question.... confused??? or there is one way of getting only one solution......

Comment: Working backwards is definitely the way to go.  Yes, there are infinitely many solutions.  That's not a problem, you were just asked for one.

Comment: Working backwards is very good. The smallest example is with $89$ and $55$. As you go down you keep getting quotient $1$, and Fibonacci number remainders.

Comment: The fact that you get Fibonacci numbers in the smallest examples is quite profound in some sense! It's related to how fractions of consecutive Fibonacci numbers are the "hardest" to approximate by simpler fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you did:

The final line is always $a = qb + 0$, since getting the remainder $0$ is how you know when to stop. So pick some $q$ and $b$ and then $a$ must be $qb$. Let's pick $q = 2$, $b = 1$, so the last line is $2 = 2\cdot 1 + 0$. How did we get there? Well, when you have some line $a = qb + r$ and $r \not= 0$, then for the next line you divide $b$ by $r$. So whatever the line before $2 = 2\cdot 1 + 0$ was, it must have had $r = 1$ and $b = 2$. So let's pick some other $q$, say $q = 3$, and get $7 = 3\cdot 2 + 1$. Similarly, the line before that might have been (pick $q = 2$) $16 = 2 \cdot 7 + 2$.

You can continue in this way for as long as you like. At every stage you are picking a $q$, which you can pick to be whatever positive integer you want, so all the possible ways of running Euclid's algorithm in $n$ steps correspond to all possible choices of $n + 1$ (remember at the last step we chose $b$ as well!) positive integers.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help but I am trying to do this using the backward steps which I have followed some steps in the given example ends up with :1=7+(-3)(2) =7+(-3)*[16+(-2)(7)] and I am stuck of carrying out the third step as it did not satisfy the equations and end up with a negative number..... need help!!!.... please can anyone help me.....

Answer (score 0):

I like to answer questions directly: your question is very clear and I think the answer should be too, so here's the answer: yes, what you have done is right. Well done. I do think it would be interesting, as mentioned above, to know how you found a and b.