# Find two integers for which the Euclidean algorithm will take 6 steps?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, euclidean-algorithm

How does one approach this? Is it just trial or is there a method to find this if asked to find such numbers for a particular number of steps.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482694/choosing-two-numbers-a-b-such-that-the-euclidean-algorithm-takes-10-steps?rq=1

Comment: You may consider two consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Great I'll try that right now.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but don't two consecutive Fibonacci numbers makes the Euclidean algorithm to terminate after 8 steps. I just tried it with gcd(55,34) and gcd(89,34). Both gave me 8 steps.

Comment: 34 and 89 are not consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: yes you are correct i meant to write gcd(89,55)

Comment: @winterMute I am not sure how exactly you count the number of steps, but did you try gcd(21,13) or gcd(34,21)?

Comment: @bram28 Thank you for your suggestion, I figured out how to do it by working backwards.